# How to filter same result when click to previous page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a search filter for the orders when ever Im onclick for detail page and going back to previous page. The searched filter is not showing and as default im getting all the list of orders.

But i need to get only what i already  filtered the order

Created useeffect to filters but when im click using onclick function.As a default it showing all orders

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [searchParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page) in your **server component**.

For instance, you have a page called orders and you navigate to it like that

http://localhost:3000/orders #1 (you see 4 orders)

Then you have filtered orders by category using this url

http://localhost:3000/orders?category=tablet #2 (you see 2 orders)

Finally, you navigated to another link

http://localhost:3000/product/1 #3

At this point, you should be redirected to url #2 in which your orders are filtered by category when you hit the back button of your browser. (you see 2 orders again)

Here's your orders page

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Orders({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) {
  let orders = [
    { id: 1, category: 'tablet', name: 'ipad' },
    { id: 2, category: 'tablet', name: 'nest hub' },
    { id: 3, category: 'phone', name: 'iphone' },
    { id: 4, category: 'phone', name: 'samsung' },
  ];

  let filteredOrders =
    searchParams && searchParams.category
      ? orders.filter((o) => o.category == searchParams.category)
      : orders;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {filteredOrders &&
        filteredOrders.map((item, index) => {
          return <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>;
        })}
      <button>Filter</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```